# React useQuery - useMutation onError not catching

Tags: axios, react-query, onerror

I'm using a combination of Axios and react-query to make a POST request to a server that may answer with response code 400 and validation errors.

```
export const axiosDefault = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_LINK,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})

const contactMutation = useMutation(
    (data) => axiosDefault.post('/contact', data),
    {
        onSuccess: (response) => {
            console.log('Success', response)
        },
        onError: (error) => {
           console.log('Error', error)
        }
    }
)
```

However, when calling `contactMutation.mutate(someData)` the error response from the server does not get processed by the react query library and instead propagates upward. Neither the `onSuccess` or `onError` handlers get called, the `isError` property of the mutation is also not set.

I've spent hours tearing my hair out over this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: code looks correct on first sight. Can you show a codesandbox reproduction with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

hi i also had same issue i solved by wrapping api function to try/catch block and throw the catched Error.

```
(data) => {
    try {
       axiosDefault.post('/contact', data),
    } catch (error) {
       throw error
    }
 }
```

Comment: this fixed my issue also, but why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `contactMutation.mutate(someData)` use **mutateAsync** like `contactMutation.mutateAsync(someData)`

Source : https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/3575